# How to do emergency upgrade to kernel 4.14.13?

Tags: software-installation, kernel, dpkg

I hope the 4.15 kernel is out soon.

My PC got bricked by the Intel related updates to the Kernel.

How do I upgrade to Ubuntu's latest mainline (stable) [kernel version 4.14.13](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14.13/)?

THIS DOESN'T WORK:

> ```
> wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14.13/linux-headers-4.14.13-041413_4.14.13-041413.201801101001_all.deb
> wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14.13/linux-headers-4.14.13-041413-generic_4.14.13-041413.201801101001_amd64.deb
> wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14.13/linux-image-4.14.13-041413-generic_4.14.13-041413.201801101001_amd64.deb
> ```
>
> Step 2: After successfully downloading install it
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.14.13-* linux-image-4.14.13-* .deb
> ```
>
> Step 3: Verify installed Version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Comment: You do understand those mainline kernels are non - standard, intended for testing only, and unsupported ?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not an error description.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Voting to Reopen. I think the question is pretty clear. OP needs a fix for a broken Intel feature. The fix is only available in Kernel `4.14.13` and OP wants to install it. This could be a duplicate of many questions of how to install latest mainline kernel though.

Comment: there are directions here https://askubuntu.com/a/995649/694267.

Comment: Stackoverflow sucks. I want to delete this question and I CAN'T!

Comment: There are 4 reopen votes on your question and I've written an answer partially based on your question but cannot post it here because the question is closed. So I had to post it [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948)

Answer (score 4):

The command line to install the kernel image has an empty space before the ".deb", enter the following line instead:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.14.13-* linux-image-4.14.13-*.deb
```

Comment: I should mention there are easier ways than using `wget` in CLI which your answer doesn't touch on. ie: https://askubuntu.com/questions/879888/how-do-i-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version/879920#879920

Comment: Both methods don't work reliably in the current Meltdown/Spectre mess. I think this discussion is better suited on reddit.com